# Is there a keyboard way to navigate items in Illustrator's layers panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, cc-2014

I've got lots items in the layers panel that I need to group, re-arrange, re-name etc and it'd be nice to be able to do it all with just keyboard. What shortcuts, or keys can I use?

I did google (cursorily) but I needed an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator does not provide keyboard shortcuts for layer panel navigation, beyond the standard "new layer" shortcut. Objects can be moved through a layer stack via the keyboard, but layers themselves can not be reordered or selected with the keyboard.

Comment: I agree that there is no "Official" shortcuts for layer panels but OP wants to know if there is any way or not and I think using "Actions + Scripts" may complete that blank space :) isn't it should work? and perhaps it seems OP already got answer ;)

Comment: @Mr.Online Is this still a valid answer?

Comment: @HermanToothrot yes! but you need to give it a try according to your need. for example you want layer "x" to be selected then you can script it since action only can "clone" but can't think smartly!